# Main subatomic particles

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, definition, elementary-particles

I've come across a question that asks what the subatomic particles are. The answer being the proton, neutron and electron. However, from my understanding subatomic particles also include quarks etc. So what do main subatomic particles even mean? Could someone please provide a cited definition for subatomic particles?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle

Comment: You can find the answers to these kinds of questions by doing a good internet search. There are many sources including Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

Any particle smaller, or structurally less-than-an-atom, is a subatomic particle. Ofc, this includes the elementary particles: 6 quarks, 3 charged leptons, and 3 neutrinos....plus the bosons.

It also includes protons and neutrons, and all the other baryons (https://pdg.lbl.gov/2022/tables/contents_tables_baryons.html), and ofc all the mesons (https://pdg.lbl.gov/2020/tables/contents_tables_mesons.html), which together, compose the Particle Zoo.